# Can tools like pep8 and pyflakes be called from within emacs?

Tags: python

I've been doing a lot of python coding. I often find myself checking my code by

1. saving my file
2. opening a terminal
3. issuing `$ pep8 my_file.py`
4. issuing `$ pyflakes my_file.py`

It would be cool if I could maybe bind `$ pep8 my_current_script.py` and `$ pyflakes my_current_script.py` to a key combination and have the results pop up in a new buffer. Is this possible in emacs?

Comment: I think `elpy` package provides this functionality.

Comment: yes, you can even have the errors warnings highlighted during you code. Some doc about pylint and pep8: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Python#Code_Checker

Answer (score 1):

Nearly anything is possible in Emacs.

You can install the package [`flycheck`](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck). `flake8` is the default checker, but you can choose others, such as `pylint` or [`pyflakes`](https://github.com/Wilfred/flycheck-pyflakes).

All you need to do is:

Add MELPA putting putting this in your `.emacs` or evaluating it with `M-:`:

```el
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Install `flycheck`:

```el
M-x package-install RET flycheck RET
```

Activate it:

```el
M-x flycheck-mode RET
```

I use this configuration in my `.emacs`:

```el
(package-initialize)
(require 'flycheck)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

Comment: This does not check variable names like if I write `helloWorld` instead of `hello_world`. @nanny